# Mailers sends empty content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, exception-notification

Using Rails 3.1.1 and Heroku + exception_notification gem 3.0.0

Starting yesterday I started receiving my notification_notifier emails with an empty content. The subject and all is just as it used to be but the "message has no content". It usually consists of log data, which page the error occurred on etc.

I am not sure what I could have done. I could have upgraded the gem recently but I am not sure, and I am not sure which version to downgrade to in that case.

UPDATE: It turned out that ALL emails sent from the app are delivered without content ("tell a friend", "feedback to webmaster" etc) and not only exception_notification. So this is NOT an exception_notification error.

Has anyone else seen this? Do you know what I could have done wrong? How can I trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to a coding error in an initializer. Useless to explain exactly what since this is unique to my app. Sorry for a bad question and useless answer :/